Xamarin Android Otp Sms Autofill without sms permissions
Is it possible to autofill/read OTP SMS in xamarin forms android without using permission?
I researched but couldn't find an example other than broadcast. Is there "AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP" support in Xamarin like in native android?

Do you want to find this: OTP SMS Autofill without using SMS permissions?

I couldn't understand where you read the SMS

Can you elaborate on the specific code you're working on now, and where is the code going wrong?

How can I read SMS without SMS permissions in Xamarin forms android platform? Does this link include this? Where?

@JessieZhang-MSFT Do you have any information on this subject?

I just came across this article Verify OTP Automatically In Android Without SMS Read Permission Using Xamarin.Forms which mentions that an Android App should read the SMS for some specific needs like to verify OTP. The Google Play Service has enabled Android SMS Retriever API that allows you to access the SMS messages and verify it via SMS without device permissions, you can try it first.
